# Showing a function is measurable iff their product is

Tags: probability

Suppose $f = (f_1, f_2 ) : \Omega \to E \times F $. $f: (\Omega, \mathcal{A}) \to (E \times F, \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F} ) $  is measurable iff $f_1: (\Omega, \mathcal{A}) \to (E, \mathcal{E} ) $ and $f_2: (\Omega, \mathcal{A}) \to ( F, \mathcal{F} $) is measurable:

for any $U \in \mathcal{E}, V \in \mathcal{F} $, we know $f_i$ is measure if $f^{-1}_1(U), f^{-1}_2 (V) \in \mathcal{A} $. How can I use this to show the conclusion? Inst it trivial?

Comment: Because for any measurable rectangle $A \times B$ you have $f^{-1}(A \times B) = f_1^{-1}(A) \cap f_2^{-1}(B)$ and the latter set is measurable.

Comment: Why is it $f^{-1}(A \times B) = f^{-1}_1(A) \cap f^{-1}_2(B) $ ?

Comment: $f(\omega) \in A \times B$ **iff** $f_1(\omega) \in A$ **and** $f_2(\omega) \in B$.